# Cross filtering in GRAFANA

Tags: filter, grafana

I need to implement cross filtering in Grafana (i.e. by clicking a data point in one dashboard tile to have all dashboard tiles automatically filter on that value)
I know cross filtering is not currently available in Grafana, but I was wondering if there is a workaround to get the job done.
Being such a basic need, I'm sure someone has done this before.